# Filter values before aggregating to a number on DataDog "query_value" visualization

Tags: datadog

I have a counting metric in DataDog, that has positive and negative counts.  When using a "timeseries" visualization to show only the positive counts, I simply just apply a `clamp_min(query1, 0)`, and it works.

Essentially, the JSON looks like below for the "timeseries"

```json
{
    "viz": "timeseries",
    "requests": [
        {
            "style": {
                "palette": "dog_classic",
                "type": "solid",
                "width": "normal"
            },
            "type": "line",
            "formulas": [
                {
                    "formula": "clamp_min(query1, 0)"
                }
            ],
            "response_format": "timeseries",
            "queries": [
                {
                    "query": "sum:my_counting_metric.as_count()",
                    "data_source": "metrics",
                    "name": "query1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to do this same thing, and aggregate all these positive numbers that I've filtered for on a "query_value" viz, I can't find a single way to do anything similar because it sums all the counts to a number before making it possible to apply filters like `clamp_min` above.  Ideally, I would like to do something like below if possible.

```json
{
    "viz": "query_value",
    "requests": [
        {
            "response_format": "scalar",
            "formulas": [
                {
                    "formula": "query1"
                }
            ],
            "queries": [
                {
                    "query": "sum:clamp_min(my_counting_metric.as_count(), 0)",
                    "data_source": "metrics",
                    "name": "query1",
                    "aggregator": "avg"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "precision": 2,
    "autoscale": true
}
```

Is there any way to do this?  I'm feeling pretty stuck and would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: have you tried using `cutoff_min`?

Comment: @bwest I haven't and went ahead and tried it out just now.  The reason it doesn't appear to work is the same as why `clamp_min` didn't work: "sum" aggregates everything to a value first, not allowing any filtering of the values before aggregation when using the "query_value" visualization in DD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get in contact with DataDog on this question.

They basically told me this behavior mentioned in my post is expected because the "query_value" viz runs a procedure called point reduction.  This is why the `clamp_min` function had no effect.  To put it short, *there's not a way to filter/map before the execution of the initial aggregating function on a "query_value" viz*.